# Edit text Textarea Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Textarea which is in a form that has this value

```
Hello<div class="author"><br /><i> Written By <a href="http://localhost/user/admin">admin</a> </i></div>
```

I need to remove everything in the author class on load cause i will be adding the same updated data on submit.

Comment: Read the Question to the end.

Comment: Everything inside the `author` class and leave an empty `div`? Or, remove the `author` div and leave just `Hello`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace that piece with regex:

```
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/<div class="author">.*?<\/div>/, ''));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/Nzvy7/

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear from the question, but to remove the `<div class="author">` and its contents you can use `split` and `shift`:

```
$("textarea").val().split("<div class=\"author\"").shift();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtnL7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are looking for, but how exactly do you add text to the textarea on submit, and why don't just use the same method for removing text.

On the other hand doing:

```
$('#textareaID').val('Hello');
```

Will give you exactly the same result as removing the rest of the text and just keeping 'Hello'.